# Ionic 2 SQLite Native as a Service

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2

Anyone had success creating a service out of the SQLite ionic-native?

So one could end up with something like `addItem(param)`, `editItem(param)`, which calls the respective service function to handle the task?

With `Storage` and `SqlStorage`, I could do something like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Storage, SqlStorage } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {     
  constructor() {

    this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);

    this.storage.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, type TEXT)');
  }

  saveCategory(data) {
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO category (name, type) VALUES (?, ?)';
    return this.storage.query(sql, [data.name, data.type]);
  }
}
```

I've been reading the docs about using the SQLite in Ionic, and I'm not understanding how to do something along the lines of the above, Doc: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/

How do you do it?

Comment: @suraj You do realize this question is about using the SQLite Native, and nothing else, right?

Comment: The example you used is actually a service CategoryService, What is your question ? Do you need a explaination on how it works ? Don't treat SQLite like Json

Comment: @LeRoy No, not how it works. I'm asking how I can do something similar, create a service, using the SQLite Native Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem is.. here is how i use it

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class DBService {

    private db: SQLite;

    constructor() {
        this.db = null;
    };

    public open() {
        if (window.sqlitePlugin) {
            this.db = new SQLite();
        } else { //handle in desktop if needed }
    };
 }

// other methods
```